# Why doesnt this Javascript regular expression work

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var existing = "";   
if(disk.isLinux){   
    var valinvalid = "/usr" ;            
    var valinput = /^\/[a-zA-Z]{2,}/ ;  
    if(!valinput.match(valinvalid)){      
        return "^/" + existing + "[^/][a-zA-Z]{2,}[^/]$";
    } 
}
```

Here im trying to do the following in the first if condition ie. if(disk.isLinux):
1. there should be minimum 3 characters
2. the first character should be /
3. the entire input shouldnt match "/usr". But it can be /us or /usra

Comment: Could you postr some examples of what should match and what shouldn't?

Comment: Other than the default linux directories like /usr, /root etc... anything else with minimum 3 characters and starting with / is a valid input

Comment: Try running it on http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html. It worked for me on Firefox and Chrome

Comment: mgibsonbr: thanks for the reforemat :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to test if it matches, us test on regexp:

```
/^\/[\w]{2,}/.test("/usr/");     //true
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you guys for your support   
return "^/" + existing + "(?!usr$)[a-zA-Z]{0,}$";- This worked.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) vars should never ever ever be inside if statements

2) String.prototype.match exists RegExp.prototype.match does not

But more importantly, you dont need regEx at all

```
if (
 input.length < 3 ||
 input.charAt(0) !== '/' ||
 input === '/user'
) {
 throw new Error("I'm not happy with the input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code to use:

```
var valinput = new RegExp("/^\/[a-zA-Z]{2,}/") ;  
 if(!valinput.test(valinvalid)){
```